# How do I install and run django on iPage (a shared webhost)?

Tags: web-hosting, django, python

I am using an iPage hosted server and I am willing to use django. As per the provider, they support python inside cgi-bin dir. I would like to know how do I install django on a cgi server if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tutorial - http://joemaller.com/1467/django-via-cgi-on-shared-hosting/

> Running Django under CGI is not impossible. It just kind of really
>   sucks.

Someone else tried it on the same host and hit a problem, but got a solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340996/hosting-django-on-a-shared-fastcgi-host

Other tutorials are available http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=django+install+cgi-bin&qscrl=1

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether they support django or you can ask them to install it for you. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

August 2013 : ipage has confirmed that they don't support python frameworks.